# How to change the Color of the text on image using BufferedImage?

Tags: java, graphics, bufferedimage

Using `BufferedImage bgImage` I want to set a black color for the text on the image.

```
BufferedImage bgImage = createBgImageForText();
bgImage.createGraphics().drawString(player.getPlayerName(), 25, 15);
if ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(player.getCaptain())) {
    bgImage.createGraphics().setPaint(Color.BLACK);
} else {
    bgImage.createGraphics().setPaint(Color.WHITE);
}

mainImg.getGraphics().drawImage(bgImage, 10, 10, null);
```

But the text is always white by default.
How to change the color of the text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to store the `Graphics` instance you create with `bgImage.createGraphics()` and then you can set the color *before* drawing the text:

```
BufferedImage bgImage = createBgImageForText();
Graphics2D g = bgImage.createGraphics();
if ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(player.getCaptain())) {
    g.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
} else {
    g.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
}
g.drawString(player.getPlayerName(), 25, 15);
g.dispose();
```

Comment: **Hint**: You can beautify the painting process by applying [rendering hints](http://derek.dkit.ie/java/rendering_hints.html) to the graphics instance ``g``.

Comment: Cast to Graphics2D not needed. For good order do a `g.dispose();` afterwards.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thanks for the ``#dispose`` hint. The cast is not needed, but you can do more with the graphics instance when it's known to operate on two dimensions.

Comment: @JoopEggen You're right, I coded by hand when answering, removing obsolete cast...